# Style lost when another control with the same style loaded in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

In my WPF application, I am getting a strange behavior where the buttons lose the style at run time.

The buttons give up the style when another user control containing the buttons with the same style is loaded.

Here is the style definition in App.xaml:

```
   <Style x:Key="SaveButton" TargetType="telerik:RadButton">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Save"/>
                    <Image Source="Resources\icons\save.png" Margin="5" 
                    Height="16" Width="16"></Image>
                </StackPanel>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

A window with a button carrying the style SaveButton is loaded properly. But from this window when another user control is loaded carrying one more button with the same style of SaveButton, User control button displays properly but the button on the window turns completely blank (no margins, no image, no text).

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: Try to set the build action of the PNG to _Resource_

Comment: @BionicCode Build action is already set to Resource. That is not the problem as no style attribute takes effect. And also, it perfectly appears for the initial control.

Comment: Sorry, but have you tried to set `x:Shared="False"`on the `Style`? The content (`Image`) can not be shared as it is explicitly assigned as content of a `Control`. To do it without `x:Shared="False"` override the template of the `Button`.

Comment: @BionicCode I could not find such property (only x:Key, x:Name, x:UID, x:FieldModifier are there). Further, based on your advice, I took the Image completely out from the style, but still, it is giving me the same problem.

Comment: That's strange. There must be a Shared property for sure. then try to replace the content setter with this: `<Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="telerik:RadButton">
                <Border Background="Blue">
                  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">` ...

Comment: ... `<TextBlock Margin="5"
                               Text="Save" />
                    <Image Source="Resources\icons\save.png"
                           Margin="5"
                           Height="16"
                           Width="16">
                    </Image>
                  </StackPanel>
                </Border>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>`

Comment: There must be the `x:Shared` attribute on the`Style` tag

Comment: @BionicCode I don't want to use ControlTemplate, as I am using 3rd party (Telerik) controls. It will remove the basic styling of the button. However, using this approach the problem does not arise. I am sure, you are right by saying that there is some content (image) sharing issue.

Comment: In the XAML desiger click on the RadButton control. Then go to the properties pane. Open the 'Miscellaneous' section an click on the square next to the Template field. Choose 'Convert To New Resource'. Now give it a name. You can now modify the original template. Just keep the part names and everything will work.

Comment: This could be helpful for you: [Telerik - UI for WPF: Editing Control Templates](Editing Control Templates)

Comment: I still can't believe that you don't see the x:Shared attribute. What error do you get when you set it on the Style tag?

Comment: It did not come in intellisense. But now as I put it there, it did not show any compile time error either. As it happened, this was the solution to my problem. Thank you

Comment: Nice. I was so absolutely sure that it has to be like this. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @BionicCode Thanks for your help. It would be great if you post your answer instead of putting it in the comment. I will mark it as Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you set the the `Content` property of the `Button` explicitly, its value  can only be applied once. By default the XAML attribute `x:Shared` is set to true. This means that any given resource request always returns the same instance. In your case this means that each time the `Style`is applied, the same value of `ContentControl.Content` is applied. To omit this, you have three options.

The first option is to set the XAML attribute on the `Style` tag to `False`:

`<Style x:Shared=False ...></Style>`

The second option is to override the `ControlTemplate` of the `Control`:

```
<Style ...>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Save"/>
                    <Image Source="Resources\icons\save.png" Margin="5" 
                    Height="16" Width="16"></Image>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The third option is to override the `ContentControl.ContentTemplate` directly:

```
<Style ...">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Save"/>
                    <Image Source="Resources\icons\save.png" Margin="5" 
                    Height="16" Width="16"></Image>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```